# Amazon SNS topic subscribe but nothing else send

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, callback, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I received the JSON SubscriptionConfirmation message from Amazon SNS and I succesfully confirmed subscription.

But since almost 1 hour, I did not received anything else, however I am currently sending emails via Amazon SES...

The server is configured and call my Amazon SNS topic.

```
Current notification configuration:
Email Feedback Forwarding: disabled
Bounce Notifications SNS Topic: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:437351776702:My-topic
Complaint Notifications SNS Topic: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:437351776702:My-topic
Delivery Notifications SNS Topic: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:437351776702:My-topic
```

Thanks for help

Comment: I didnt get your question? Can you please explain?

Comment: My callback is never called by Amazon SNS, aside from the subscription confirmation message...

Comment: The first thing I'd try is directly sending a message to your topics in the console. If that works you know the topic is setup correctly for you to receive an email notification.